# GeoServer - Web application

Tags: geoserver, spatial-database, drupal, cartaro

for a science project at university I have the task to create a web application based on Geoserver. The data is already stored, I have to visualize it now on the web for different users. Each user can only see certain layers. 
I only have basic programming skills but experience in Drupal.

Would Cartaro be a good solution for this?